# SQL: getting around having to do bitshift on binary column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

I have table A which stores id as binary(16). Something like 0x12345678.
I also have table B which stores id as varbinary(80) column. This column references the same ids as table A, but each id has an extra padding of '10' in front of it. Like so: 0x101234567.

I need to run a join on these two tables, and therefore need to find a way to convert between those two formats.

Technically, i could do this by doing a bitshift, but as far as i know it is not supported for binary type.

I tried to convert the value to BIGINT, do the shift there and then to concert it back to binary, but BIGINT is not enough to hold the value, so i end up losing all of the high order digits.

I imagine there should be a straight forward way to do this, which i cant think of.

Comment: Binary values support concatenation. It's one of the few operations they do support. `0x10 + 0x12345678 = 0x1012345678`.

Comment: you could also do an "and" operation to get the part you want to compare.

Comment: ...of course, long term you should fix your key columns.  Having to perform any operation in a join tends to negate the use of indices, and having multi-part keys is against good normalization practices, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bitwise like so

```
  WHERE colA & 0xFFFFFFF = colB & 0xFFFFFFF
```

depending on the optimizer this may be faster than a concat (since bitwise and is very fast operation for a CPU).

Comment: Bitwise operations are not supported on arbitrary `(VAR)BINARY`, only on `BINARY` combined with `INT`/`BIGINT`. In general, you can't use them unless `colA` and `colB` happen to be properly sized for conversion to `INT`/`BIGINT` (and `BINARY(16)` is too large for that). Of course, if all values happen to be smaller than the declared data types (like in the question's example) you're in luck.

Comment: @JeroenMostert -- I guess you can pick the "part" you need to mask and mask that as needed.   Just some fancy casting to ints would be needed... so my answer is more of a guideline.